# Embedding the developer story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I'd like to embed the developer story on my own website. This doesn't currently seem to be supported though. Are there any plans to support this?

I've tried some ways of bypassing all safety-features SO implemented over the years and effectively undoing hours of work by the SO-employees and developers, and came up with this highly immoral piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fillIframe(){
var string = `<?php
$page = file_get_contents("https://stackoverflow.com/story/danielvandenberg");

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
if($nodes->item(0)) {
    $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($nodes->item(0));
}
$page = $dom->saveHTML();
$page = json_encode($page);
$page = substr($page, 1, -1);
echo $page;
?>`;
//document.getElementById("developerStory").contentDocument.write("hi");
document.getElementById("developerStory").contentDocument.write(string);
}
</script>
<iframe id="developerStory" width="100%" height="100%" onload="fillIframe()"/>
```

And I guess it kinda works, except for showing some really weird symbols. Sigh, encodings… If you wanna see for yourself, see https://vandenberg.us.to/developer-story/

Comment: You could use iframes... if X-Frame-Options permitted cross-origin framing. But you can still fetch it server-side.

Comment: @DanielA.White I know… As stated, highly immoral.

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` is set to `SAMEORIGIN` as seen on http://headers.cloxy.net/.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's not something we have planned right now, but we may consider adding the ability to embed in the future.

Comment: Eliminate weird symbols by changing loadHTML line:

`$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($page, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));`

Fetching serverside works. Confirmed.